# Install init script after RPM install

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have this spec file which is used to extract files into directory:

```
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Linux Agent installation script
Group:          Utilities
License:        license
Source0:        agent-1.0.tar.gz
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
%description

%prep
%setup -q -n agent

%build

%install
install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/agent
cp -a * %{buildroot}/agent

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
/agent
%defattr(-,root,root,-)

%doc
%changelog
```

I want to modify the RPM package also to install init scripts into Linux.

I want to run these commands after RPM install:

ln -s /agent/apache-karaf-4.0.0/bin/karaf-service /etc/init.d/

/etc/init.d/karaf-service start

Which approach is better:
- Copy the files after they are extracted
- Copy the files from the RPM

I'm not very familiar, can you give advice and how I can implement the commands into spec file?

Comment: Is this something you want the RPM itself to do? Does your RPM really install files into `/agent`? Because that's a pretty horrible place for things. Where does `/opt/apache-karaf-4.0.0/bin/karaf-service` come from? Some other RPM? If you are depending on some other RPM you should list it in a `Requires:` line.

Comment: Yes, I want RPM to do it. I'm using /agent just for development purposes. `/agent/apache-karaf-4.0.0/bin/karaf-service` - it's placed into the RPM

Comment: Don't use something under `/` that's just bad practice. Use `/opt` like in your link command or just about anything else but `/`. Anyway. If the service file is in your RPM then you can just create the link in the buildroot and add it to `%files` and/or just create the actual file in `/etc/init.d` in the buildroot and include *that* in `%files`.

Comment: @EtanReisner can you make this official answer with example please?

Answer (score 1):

See:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets#Systemd

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd?#Filesystem_locations

Note that automatically enable service is not generally good approach as installations can be in changeroots, in an installer context, or in other situations where you don't want the services autostarted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install files to anywhere directly under `/` it is bad practice. If you need an entire hierarchy of your own use `/opt/agent`. If you want to integrate with the system cleanly then just use `/usr` like system packages.

If the service file in question is in this RPM then you can install it to `%{buildroot}/opt/agent/apache-karaf-4.0.0/bin/karaf-service` (or wherever) and create the `${buildroot}/etc/init.d/karaf-service` link during `%install` and then include both of those files in the `%files` section.

Comment: Can you show me how I can define this please into spec file.